# Sleep for X seconds before posting API - Python

Tags: python

I need to post some records to the website. I feel I am done with the complex part - the code itself, now I need to tweak the code so that my account doesn't get blocked when doing the posting - yep, just happened.

```
#importing libraries
import csv
import json

#changing data type
field_types = [('subject', str),
('description', str),
('email', str)]
output = []

#opening the raw file
with open('file.csv','r',encoding = 'utf-8-sig') as f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(f):
        row.update((key, conversion(row[key]))
        for key, conversion in field_types)
        output.append(row) #appending rows
    with open('tickets.json','w') as outfile: #saving records as json
        json.dump(output,outfile,sort_keys = True, indent = 4)
with open('tickets.json','r')as infile:
    indata = json.load(infile)
output =[]
for data in indata:
    r= requests.post("https://"+ domain +".domain.com/api/", auth = (api_key, password), headers = headers, json=data)
    output.append(json.loads(r.text))
#saving the response code
with open('response.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(output, outfile, indent = 4)
```

I searched and found time.sleep(5) but now sure how to use it. Will it go before `output.append(json.loads(r.text))`?

Comment: It's just important that it goes anywhere in your for loop.

Comment: Will it go before r?

Comment: you can add it after `output.append` line  , inside the loop itself.  so that after each iteration you will give a gap of 5 - which ensures before next request you have waited this long

Comment: OK, that's what I thought! Thank you!